# Is this a real dinosaur species?

Tags: dinosaurs

I recently got [image: this toy dinosaur] and would like to know if this is a real species. It doesn’t look quite like a Styracosaurus, but is close. Can someone identify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's an Achelousaurus.

Two curved horns on top, plus hump on nose:
**Front view:**

[image: achelousaurus]

**Side view: (for nose)**
[image: achelousaurus side]